# pygame making the sprite go upwards and downwards

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to make the sprite move up and down by using the arrow keys but it schemes to only be moving slightly upwards and slightly downwards: there is a speed for the x and y axis and also a position. There are also two functions which are draw and update (which gets the new xpos and the new ypos). here is my code

```
import pygame
import random
import sys

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1280, 720))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()  # A clock to limit the frame rate.
pygame.display.set_caption("this game")


class Background:
    picture = pygame.image.load("C:/images/cliff.jpg").convert()
    picture = pygame.transform.scale(picture, (1280, 720))

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.xpos = x
        self.ypos = y

    def draw(self):
        screen.blit(self.picture, (self.xpos, self.ypos))


class player_first:
    picture = pygame.image.load("C:/aliens/ezgif.com-crop.gif")
    picture = pygame.transform.scale(picture, (200, 200))

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.xpos = x
        self.ypos = y
        self.speed_x = 0
        self.speed_y = 0
        self.rect = self.picture.get_rect()


    def update(self):
        self.xpos =+ self.speed_x
        self.ypos =+ self.speed_y

    def draw(self):      #left right
        #screen.blit(pygame.transform.flip(self.picture, True, False), self.rect)
        screen.blit(self.picture, (self.xpos, self.ypos))







class Bullet_player_1(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    picture = pygame.image.load("C:/aliens/giphy.gif").convert_alpha()
    picture = pygame.transform.scale(picture, (100, 100))


    def __init__(self):
        self.xpos = 360
        self.ypos = 360
        self.speed_x = 0
        super().__init__()
        self.rect = self.picture.get_rect()


    def update(self):
        self.xpos += self.speed_x

    def draw(self):
        screen.blit(self.picture, (self.xpos, self.ypos))
        #self.screen.blit(pygame.transform.flip(self.picture, False, True), self.rect)

    def is_collided_with(self, sprite):
        return self.rect.colliderect(sprite.rect)



player_one_bullet_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
player_one = player_first(0, 0)
cliff = Background(0, 0)

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                    player_one.speed_y = -5
                    print("up")

                elif event.key == pygame.K_s:
                    player_one.speed_y = 5
                    print("down")



                elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                    bullet_player_one = Bullet_player_1

                    bullet_player_one.ypos = player_one.ypos
                    bullet_player_one.xpos = player_one.xpos

                    bullet_player_one.speed_x = 14

                    player_one_bullet_list.add(bullet_player_one)




            elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_d and player_one.speed_x > 0:
                    player_one.speed_x = 0
                elif event.key == pygame.K_a and player_one.speed_x < 0:
                    player_one.speed_x = 0



    player_one.update()
    cliff.draw()
    player_one.draw()

    player_one_bullet_list.update()

    for bullet_player_one in player_one_bullet_list:
            bullet_player_one.draw()



    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)
```

Answer (score 1):

You've written `self.xpos =+ self.speed_x` (which is interpret as `self.xpos = +self.speed_x`) instead of `self.xpos += self.speed_x`. So you're not adding the speed to the position, you're overwriting it.

Comment: can you try and help me with when the KEY is released to stop the character from moving

Comment: If this answered your question, feel free to mark it as accepted. Otherwise, say if it doesn't answer it. If you have another question, then search for it here on Stackoverflow, and if doesn't exist, create a new question. To help you along, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42700883/6486738) gives a solution to that question.

Comment: Thanks but it did not help can you please try and help me with when the key is released that the ship can stop moving

Comment: @Will.2004 I don't quite understand. Is that a new question or the same question as the post? I don't know what the ship is; is it the player? In that case, you have an if-statement in order to stop it for the x-axis; doesn't it work or do you want it to stop in the y-axis as well? [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41911301/6486738) is another answer that shows another technique for handling input which will allow your player to both move and stop correctly.

Comment: Yes, its the same question: "can you try and help me with when the KEY is released to stop the character from moving" and the ship is the player

Comment: @Will.2004 I meant if it is the question you've posted at the top of the page? I never read that you wanted to stop the movement of your player in your original post, but rather that it only moved slightly up and down. Did my answer fix that? And about trying to stop the player when the key is released; didn't any of my links answer that question? And if not, what about the question _"you have an if-statement in order to stop it for the x-axis; doesn't it work or do you want it to stop in the y-axis as well?"_

Comment: No. The examples just confused me even more. I am also slightly confused about the question "you have an if statement in order to stop it for the x axis. could you try and explain where it is in my code

Comment: its fine now I has seen where the problem was